# Why doesn't Python's OS module name its functions after their UNIX counterparts?

Tags: python, python-module

Some confusions and what they could be named instead:

`os.chdir()` could be `os.cd()`

`os.getcwd()` could be `os.pwd()`

`os.listdir` could be `os.ls()`

These would be a lot more straightforward to users used to UNIX nomenclature.

Comment: [`chdir`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/chdir.html) and [`getcwd`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getcwd.html) *are* the names of the Unix counterparts.

Comment: @jwodder That's incorrect, they're called cd and pwd on Unix.

Comment: Python is wrapping the system call `chdir` (which the shell command `cd` also wraps).

Comment: @PascLeRasc: Those may be the names of the *commands* but not the C *functions*.  `os` is a collection of functions, and so it makes sense to use those names.

Comment: Also, `os` is the platform-agnostic library; there's no reason for it to use names from any particular operating system.

Comment: @PascLeRasc he just linked to the POSIX standards, dude.

Answer (score 5):

The functions in the `os` module are named after the corresponding C library routines, not shell commands. `chdir` and `getcwd` are the names of the C functions for changing the working directory and getting the current working directory.

Also, `os` is the platform-agnostic library; there's no reason for it to use names from any particular operating system, although in this particular case it does.